# Await is reserved word even when copied from MDN

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I copied and pasted a for-await-of example from MDN and still get an error telling me await is a reserved word. Is this maybe a problem with my Javascript version?

I've tried several different methods, including IIFE's, mostly copying other people's verified code, and I get an error.

```
var asyncIterable = {
 [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
   return {
    i: 0,
    next() {
      if (this.i < 3) {
        return Promise.resolve({ value: this.i++, done: false });
      }

      return Promise.resolve({ done: true });
      }
    };
  }   
};

(async function() {
   for await (let num of asyncIterable) {
     console.log(num);
   }
})();
```

Expect it to run at the very least.

Throws error:

```
"\index.js:32
   for await (let num of asyncIterable) {"
```

Comment: Where are you running this script?

Comment: I don't believe `for await (...)` is valid syntax

Comment: Running inside atom. And i've seen for await all over the place... Do you have an idea of what it could be, if that's incorrect?

Comment: Try: `for (let num of asyncIterable) {
     console.log(await num);
   }`

Comment: "running inside atom" thats quite vague?

Comment: I mean in a file called index.js inside atom... super simple, that's the entire code.

Comment: huh... I had no idea that `for await (...)` was a thing good to know.

Comment: its not supported in IE and edge, check on MDN page.

Comment: @dankobgd, sorry but I'm failing to see what that has to do with this. No offense, just confused.

Comment: yeah its still in draft, i didn't even realize... and IE is just s**t anyway

Comment: I see. Turns out you need babel:

npm install babel-plugin-transform-async-generator-functions   babel-preset-latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll down till the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of#Specifications) section, you'll see that this is in the "draft" stage, so it is not yet fully specified, and the [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of#Browser_compatibility) is also not quite there. Your environment probably doesnt support it yet.

Comment: Okay, now @dankobgd comment makes more sense. I guess I have to assume this is the reason. Thanks! 6 min til i can accept.

Comment: For anyone looking to use it for now, install these node modules:

babel-plugin-transform-async-generator-functions
and
babel-preset-latest

Answer (score 2):

`for-await-of` loops are [available in Node.js](https://node.green/#ES2018-features-Asynchronous-Iterators-for-await-of-loops) as of `v10.3.0`.

To use the syntax, simply update your Node.js version by going to https://nodejs.org/en/ or use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: This works as well. I am sticking with node v8.12.0, however, in order for it to play nicely with a few other things I have installed. Thanks!